# How to print items within lists in a list

Tags: python

Hear me out, I do not simply want someone to solve this problem for me. I know it is not 100% complete yet, but currently when I run the program I get an error about "Can't convert 'list' object to str implicitly" I'm looking for help on how to fix this and why it is does this.

Here is the problem

Write code to print out each thing in the list of lists, L,  with a '*' after it like

> 1*2*3*4*...8*a*b*c*d*

This requires knowing the print statement and using the end or sep argument option

Here is my list, sorry for not putting it in earlier

L = [[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8],['a','b','c','d']]

Here is my code at the moment

```
def ball(x): #random function name with one parameter
    q = ''   #
    i = 0
    if type(x) != list:    #verifies input is a list
        return"Error"
    for i in x:    #Looks at each variable in list
        for j in i:    #Goes into second layer of lists
            q = q + j + '*'
    print(q)
```

Comment: When writing a question try to avoid large sections of bold writing (or any bold writing unless you really need it).  Try to include an example of the code that reproduces your problem that we can run, at the moment you've included your function but not the list you are using to call your function.

Comment: @ilent2 sorry about the bold writing, I don't know why that happened. I included the list that I need to run through the program now. Thank you so much for your corrections.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for your error

> "Can't convert 'list' object to str implicitly"

is that you're using the wrong variable in your nested `for` loops. Where you're concatenating values to your q variable, you mistakenly put `q = q + i` when you wanted `q = q + j`. You also will want to cast the value of `j` as a string so it can be concatenated with `q`. In order to get your desired output, you can simply add an asterisk into that statement - something like the following: `q = q + str(j) + '*'`. On a completely unrelated note, your `else` statement that just has `"Mistake"` in it should be removed completely - it doesn't follow an `if` and it doesn't actually return or assign to a variable.

Note that this is *not* the most elegant way to go about solving this problem. I agree with ilent2 that you should take a look at both list comprehension and the `str.join()` method.

Comment: thank you so much for taking the time to help. I added the q = q + j + '*', but I still have the same error. Thank you for your comment on removing the else statement as well.

Comment: Try doing `q = q + str(j) + '*'` - I think you're actually getting a slightly different error - where you can't concatenate a string and an integer value

Comment: that did solve the problem. Thank you so much for all you help.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a list of strings,

```
myList = ['a', '123', 'another', 'and another']
```

You can join them using the `str.join` function:

> Help on method_descriptor:
>
> join(...)
>       S.join(iterable) -> string
>
> ```
> Return a string which is the concatenation of the strings in the
> iterable.  The separator between elements is S.
> ```

```
myString = '#'.join(myList)
```

If your list contains mixed types or non-strings you need to convert each item to a string first:

```
anotherList = [1, 2, 'asdf', 'bwsg']
anotherString = '*'.join([str(s) for s in anotherList])
```

You might want to read about [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) or more about the [join function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=str%20join#str.join).  Note, the above doesn't print the output (unless you are using the interactive console), if you want the output to be printed you will need call print too

```
print myString
print anotherString
```

And, if you are working with lists-of-lists you may need to change how you convert each sub-list into a string (depending on your desired output):

```
myListList = [[1, 2, 3, 4], [2, 3, 6, 5], [6, 4, 3, 1]]
myOtherString = '#'.join(['*'.join([str(s) for s in a]) for a in myListList])
```

The last line is a little complicated to read, you might want to rewrite it as a nested for loop instead.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I am using the function in the python shell so that is where I call it. Your comment on lists inside of lists was very helpful. Thank you